# update google map on form submit

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I've been looking for a solution for hours but can't find one, I hope someone can help me as I'm new to google API, so here's what I'm trying to do: I have a form with a dynamic dropdown for region and city and based on user selection, this will update marker on google map with infowindow showing the address, lat and long..  my problem is on submitting the form, map shows blank.. here's my code:

```
var Latlong = new google.maps.LatLng(61.10802786270912, 8.883177374999718);
var map;
var geocoder;
var marker;

function initialize() {
    geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
          var mapOptions = {
            zoom: 5,
            center: Latlong
          }
            map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), mapOptions);

            marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                position: Latlong,
                map: map,
                draggable:true,
                title: "Drag Me!"
            }); 

            infowindow=new google.maps.InfoWindow();
            infowindow.setOptions({
                content: "<strong>Drag Marker</strong>"     
            });

            infowindow.open(map,marker);        

}

function newmap(selectedregion, selectedcity){
    var address = selectedregion+ "," +selectedcity;

    geocoder.geocode( { 'address': address}, function(results, status) {
        if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
          map.setCenter(results[0].geometry.location);
          map.setZoom(18);
          marker.setMap(null);
          marker = new google.maps.Marker({
              map: map,
              position: results[0].geometry.location,
              draggable:true
          });
        infowindow=new google.maps.InfoWindow();
        infowindow.setOptions({
            content: "test"
        });
        infowindow.open(map,marker);

        } else {
          alert('Geocode was not successful for the following reason: ' + status);
        }
      });   

}
```

so this code will be called on page reload:

```
$(window).load(function() {
var selectedregion = document.getElementById('region').value;
var selectedcity = document.getElementById('city').value;

if(selectedregion == "" && selectedcity == ""){
    initialize();   
}else{
    newmap(selectedregion, selectedcity);
}
});
```

It successfully calls the initialize function on first load, but it does not successfully process newmap function. I avoid using this: google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize); because everytime the form submits, googlemap goes to its default LatLng(61.10802786270912, 8.883177374999718). Can someone help me on this please..

Comment: Your code and especially newmap function worked with me. you have to show you form code as well because there could be the problem. do you return false onsubmit event with your form?

Comment: the form returns true on submit, I tried to alert(selectedregion) and alert(selectedcity) and it returns the values to me so nothings wrong with the form.. I tried to change newmap() function to testmap() with the code on initialize() and just change the LatLng coordinates and it worked well, I just could not find what's wrong with the newmap()..

Comment: as I wrote it worked well with me too so call it day ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are calling either `initialize` or `newmap` in your onload function.

`newmap` depends on initialized being run first to instantiate the geocoder and the map.

This works for me:

```
$(window).load(function() {
  var selectedregion = document.getElementById('region').value;
  var selectedcity = document.getElementById('city').value;
  initialize();

  if(selectedregion == "" && selectedcity == ""){

  }else{
    newmap(selectedregion, selectedcity);
  }
});
```

[proof of concept fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qwt5w906/1/)

Comment: Wow! I do not realize that.. that worked perfectly well! thank you so much for looking into this! I really appreciate it!  :)